# Script to move files won't work in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I have this script to move files but it keeps saying that the files are identical and therefore they cannot be written

```
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    my $id = $row[0];
    my $hash = $row[1];
    my $input_direction = '/home/input/' . $hash;
    my $output_direction = '/var/storage/'.$id;

    opendir(my $dir, $input_direction);

    while(my $file = readdir $dir){
        next if ($file eq "." or $file eq "..");
        my $from = $output_direction . "/" . "$file";
        move($from, $output_direction);
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
'/var/storage/5/.bashrc' and '/var/storage/5/.bashrc' are identical (not copied) at Move_Files.pl line 38.
Use of uninitialized value $atime in utime at /usr/share/perl5/File/Copy.pm line 393.
Use of uninitialized value $mtime in utime at /usr/share/perl5/File/Copy.pm line 393.
```

This repeats itself a few times with each file and nothing gets copies.

Any idea?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f

Comment: Tip: `my $id = $row[0]; my $hash = $row[1];` can be written as `my ($id, $hash) = @row;`

Comment: Tip: `opendir` is fairly likely to fail, so adding at least a minimal `or die $!` can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $from = $output_direction . "/" . "$file";
```

should be

```
my $from = $input_direction. "/" . "$file";
```

Better yet:

```
my $from = $input_direction. "/" . $file;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the code:

```
my $from = $output_direction . "/" . "$file";
move($from, $output_direction);
```

You probably wanted to use `$input_direction` on the former line.